# Interpret << in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How should the following code be interpreted?

```
s = "";
my_arr = [1, 2, .....]
for i in range(len(my_arr)):
    for j in range(len(my_arr)):
        if (i & (1<<j)) != 0:
            s += str(my_arr[j])
```

I cannot understand the following syntax:

```
if (i & (1<<j))!=0
```

Answer (score 0):

`<<` is a [bitwise operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators):

> x << y
>
> Returns x with the bits shifted to the left by y places (and new bits on the right-hand-side are zeros). This is the same as
>   multiplying x by 2**y.

**example**

`x << y` corresponds to `x*(2**y)`.

If `x=3` and `y=4`, `x<<y` is `3*(2**4)=3*16=48`.

In your case, since `x` is `1`, the inner for loop considers powers of 2 in that part of code.

Comment: so in this case, the outcome would be: 1*(2**y) which is 2**y